# Can I specify my own identifier ID as the relationship IDs in APOC.export?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

Currently, it seems the relationship output by apoc.export function:

```
 CALL apoc.export.csv.data( [], R, null, {stream:true}) YIELD data AS rdata
    RETURN mdata, ndata, rdata
```

The format is:

```
_start  _end    _type 
18701   19076   hasMember
```

The '18701' & '19076' are neo4j's internal ids.  Can I use my own id from the node's identifier as the relationship connector? My own node identifier is always guaranteed to be unique. I want to periodically export KG nodes and relationships as KG grows overtime. In such a case, can the IDs always be unique among all nodes in the entire graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possibility of getting duplicate nodes and relationships when using `apoc.import.csv` (even when `ignoreDuplicateNodes` is `false`, which is the default) is a known issue (see issues [1046](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/pull/1046) and [1048](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/issues/1048)).

Unfortunately, issue 1048 was closed by its submitter even though is was not fixed.
You may want to open a new issue.

Comment: I don't use the apoc.import. I just use the apoc.export. Are those IDs exported unique across the graph?

Comment: Yes, an exported node ID uniquely identifies the same node throughout a _single_ export call. But you *cannot* rely on an exported node ID to refer to the same node across multiple export calls (because the exported IDs are native IDs, and tthe native ID of a deleted node can be reused for another node).

Comment: The id of a deleted node is reused for a new node. That's OK, right? It won't wrongly identify one existing node in the graph as another existing one. My understanding the internal ID is unique across the graph, not an export call. Is that true? If this is true, I won't worry about to use the export functionality.

Comment: The unique IDs in the export file are the native IDs used by the DB used to generate the file. Upon import, neither you (not any import tool) has the ability to dictate the new native ID in the destination DB. That is the unique ID is only useful to identify nodes within the files. You need to use something else (like your own identifier properties) to correlate a node in the file to an existing node in the destination D.